# Difference of まさか and まさに

Tags: grammar

Please help understand the difference between `まさか` and `まさに`.
A look-up for meanings seems to indicate them to exactly opposite to each other.

```
まさか - not at all

まさに - surely
```

However,i have not been able to find an easy example to highlight the difference. 
Do I understand this correct?

Comment: I think the most common meaning of まさか is _impossible!_, _never!_, _no way!_. For example:

A: X-san is dead!  
B: ええ, まさか。  

To understand when / how / where to use まさに, you can take a look at these examples:
http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%BE%E3%81%95%E3%81%AB%22
If you're still in doubts after that, just ask again. :)

Comment: まさか is a guiding adverb (呼応の副詞) that leads expressions of unexpectation. It implies those things commented above but it doesn't mean them by itself like もし doesn't mean "if".

Comment: Found a nice sentence [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=sEuqaiAtmxUC&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=まさにまさか) that illustrates the difference: `「一ドル五〇円」という「まさか」は必ず起こる` ＝＝ 通貨の歴史について言えば、[金本位制](http://www.findai.com/yogo/0288.htm)の崩壊も**まさに「まさか」であった**。

Answer (score 2):

まさか means highly unlikely thing, unconceivable, no way.
まさに means exactly or just in time.

> キンメル提督は、漠然とした警告しか、ワシントンから受けていなかったので、日本軍による空襲は、まさかの出来事であった。
>
> What Admiral Kimmel got from Washington were just several vague warnings. Therefore Japanese air attack was highly unlikely thing for him.

Answer (score 0):

Masaka is used colloquially a lot like "NO WAY." and is probably equivalent to "Maji de"

Masa ni is like "truly"  and is far more likely to be found in an elegantly written novel.